# IDEA не видит ViewResolver

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jetbrains

Вот код, тут вроде всё нормально https://github.com/KaPaHgaIII/SpringOne, по крайней мере всё работает.
Но почему-то Intellij IDEA 14 продолжает подсвечивать все эти штуки, говорит "Can not resolve ..."
Раньше работало, а потом из Fasets удалил контексты, и заново создал - стало подсвечивать.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ребятушки, я нашёл частичное решение! Как я понял, это какой-то баг IDEA и вот [здесь предлагают его решение](https://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5522246;jsessionid=6294D1AE69E96378226BDECCD49C5C05#5522246). Вот, что нам нужно:

1. Заходим в Project Settings
2. Facets
3. Удаляем Spring из списка
4. Закрываем проект
5. Заново открываем проект
6. Заходим в любой конфиг Spring, среда нам автоматически предлагает сконфигурировать контекст.
7. Тыкаем ОК
8. Ура, всё* заработало!

---

*Почти всё. Заглянув в мой код (ссылка на гитхаб выше), можно увидеть что в home.jsp есть переменная success, в которую я записываю сообщение через

```
redirectAttributes.AddFlashAttribute("success","Цены увеличены")
```

А в InventoryController этого нет, поэтому IDEA не может найти её объявление. Вот скрин

[image]

Давайте прикинем, как можно безвредно отключить это предупреждение?